# How to add a UICollectionView to a SpriteKit GameViewController

Tags: uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, uicollectionview, swift3

I am trying to create a menu for my game that requires a number of effects that are part of the `UICollectionView`, so instead of reinventing the wheel, I am using a collection view which I got from [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kecV6xPTTr8) since it's close to what I want to achieve. My game begins with a posterScene which I load in the `GameViewController`, how can I replace my posterScene with my `collectionView` in `MenuViewContoller`?

Please checkout my code below:

**MenuViewController:**

```
class MenuViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.backgroundColor = .red
    cv.dataSource = self
    cv.delegate = self
    cv.isPagingEnabled = true
    return cv
}()


let cellId = "cellId"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(collectionView)

    //use autolayout instead
    collectionView.anchorToTop(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor)

    collectionView.register(PageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath as IndexPath)

    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


}

extension UIView {

func anchorToTop(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, left: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil) {

    anchorWithConstantsToTop(top: top, left: left, bottom: bottom, right: right, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0)
}

func anchorWithConstantsToTop(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, left: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, topConstant: CGFloat = 0, leftConstant: CGFloat = 0, bottomConstant: CGFloat = 0, rightConstant: CGFloat = 0) {

    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    if let top = top {
        topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: topConstant).isActive = true
    }

    if let bottom = bottom {
        bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -bottomConstant).isActive = true
    }

    if let left = left {
        leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left, constant: leftConstant).isActive = true
    }

    if let right = right {
        rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: right, constant: -rightConstant).isActive = true
    }

}

}
```

**GameViewController:**

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    let skView = self.view as? SKView

    if skView?.scene == nil  {
        skView?.showsFPS = true
        skView?.showsNodeCount = true
        skView?.showsPhysics = false
        skView?.ignoresSiblingOrder = false

         //starting the game with the Poster Scene
        let posterScene = PosterScene(size: skView!.bounds.size) 
        posterScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        skView?.presentScene(posterScene)
    }

override var shouldAutorotate : Bool {
    return true
}
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.allButUpsideDown
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden : Bool {
    return true
}
}
```

**PosterScene**

```
class PosterScene: SKScene {



override init(size: CGSize){
    super.init(size: size)
    //self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.5, y:0.5) //let's put 0,0 at the center of the screen
    let posterImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "poster")
    posterImage.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY) //CGPoint(x:736/2, y:414/2)//CGPoint.zero
    self.addChild(posterImage)
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([  SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3.0), SKAction.run({ self.changeToCollectionView() }) ])

    self.run(sequence)
}

func changeToCollectionView  ()  {

   //code for changing to collection view goes here
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

Comment: First off all, you haven't stated what is the problem and what currently happens? ... Anyways, lets say you initially load GameViewController and present some scene. If you want to load another vc, I would say you could programatically triger a segue to move to another vc. Simple as that. Or I am missing something in your question ?

Comment: @Whirlwind how would I trigger a segue? I tried adding  `menuViewController = MenuViewController()
        self.view.presentViewController(menuViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)` to my `changeToCollectionView ()` but I got a `use of unresolved identifier 'menuViewController'`. Also would you recommend I add `menuViewController` as a subView to `GameViewContoller` given the fact that I'll be changing between the `GameScene` and `MenuViewController`?

Comment: `use of unresolved identifier menuViewController`; well, did you ever create it? That usually means you never declared it, probably because you forgot the `var` or `let` keyword.

Comment: And why not just load a regular UIViewController so that all your UI objects are compatible and then make it move to an SKScene?

Comment: @JozemiteApps sorry, I forgot to declare it. Now I am getting `missing argument for parameter 'coder' in call`. Also how could I load a regular regular UIViewController to achieve what MenuViewController is doing?

Comment: just got solved it

Comment: How'd you fix it? @IronThrone